# Make std::for_each more useful - is this a good idea for the functor to know the current index?

Tags: c++, c++11, functor

Often I cannot use std::for_each because my logic for a particular element depends on its current index. To that end, I've invented a functor class which wraps the main functor and passes it the current index. Ideally I want to use it with lambda expressions. Is the class I have created safe and effective? Are there any better solutions? I did want the wrapper's operator () to return the type of the lambda expression, but I couldn't figure that out. Also, what type should I use for the index? Should I store the main functor in the wrapper by value or reference?

Thanks!

```
template<class FUNC>
class IndexFunctor
{
public:
    typedef FUNC FUNC_T;

    explicit IndexFunctor(const FUNC_T& func) : func(func), index(0) {}

    // how can this return the return type of func?
    template<class T>
    void operator ()(T& param)
    {
        func(index++, param);
    }

    const FUNC_T& GetFunctor() const
    {
        return func;
    }

    int GetIndex() const
    {
        return index;
    }

    void SetIndex(int index)
    {
        this->index = index;
    }

private:
    FUNC_T func;
    int index;
};

template<class FUNC>
IndexFunctor<FUNC> with_index(const FUNC& func)
{
    return IndexFunctor<FUNC>(func);
}

void somefunc()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), with_index([](int index, int x){ std::cout << "[" << index << "]=" << x << std::endl; }));
}
```

Comment: Some of those questions might better fit into [codereview.se].

Comment: Why not just use a `for` loop? I don’t find `std::for_each` that helpful, and I’m normally anal about using algorithms *everywhere* instead of loops.

Comment: I can't speak to Neil's situation, but it could possibly be useful in a situation where you have a pair of iterators but no way to get the size of the range yet you still need the index. Granted, a rare situation, but you never know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be safe, although it's fairly straightforward to write an indexed for-each yourself.

```
template <typename TInputIterator, typename TFunc>
TFunc counted_for_each(TInputIterator first, TInputIterator last, TFunc func)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; first != last; ++first)
    {
        func(i++, *first);
    }

    return func;
}
```

Less code and accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Wow the simplest solutions sometimes evade us! Why did I not just do that.

Comment: I would suggest considering the answer proposed by snipes83, because then you can make use of the standard library for_each and still get what you want. For example, my initial version of this loop used post-increment on `first` when it really should have used pre-increment.

Comment: I don't like that answer because I have to create an index variable outside the loop.

Comment: Fair enough. This version will produce a cleaner final result in some ways, while the other answer lets standard library writers worry about getting little details right :)

Comment: Well that is where my wrapper comes in ;)

Comment: Using `std::move` is not required here. Values used in a `return` statement are automatically rvalues. Sorry for the offtopic but this looks as disturbing as `if (someBoolean == true)` to me ;-).

Comment: Well, I will admit that I still don't fully have my head around when to use `move` and when not to. I mostly did it there because the (latest C++14 draft) standard at `for_each` says it returns `std::move(f)`, but a little research suggests it may not be a good idea to actually write it that way. I'll trust that it's bad and go ahead and remove it :)

Answer (score 4):

You problem from the start was that you wanted to keep track of an index/counter using `std::for_each`? Then one solution is to simply use a counter variable and let for instance a lambda expression capture it.

```
std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3 };

std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0;

std::for_each(begin(v), end(v), [i] (int x) mutable {
    std::cout << "[" << i++ << "]=" << x << std::endl;
});
```

Or you could simply do it like this:

```
std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0;
for (auto itr = begin(v); itr != end(v); ++itr) {
    std::cout << "[" << i++ << "]=" << *itr << std::endl;
}
```

Which in C++11 and using range-based for loop can be simplified as:

```
std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0;
for (auto itr : v) {
    std::cout << "[" << i++ << "]=" << itr << std::endl;
}
```

**Note:** in the two last examples above you must remember to reset the index counter to 0 everytime you run the for-loop.

**Update:** if you want to iterate over a subrange keeping track of the index while not wanting to have an index variable outside of the loop you could calculate the index using `std::distance` like so:

```
for (auto itr = begin(v); itr != end(v); ++itr) {
    std::cout << "[" << std::distance(begin(v),itr) << "]=" << *itr << std::endl;
}
```

Also using C++14 Generalized Lambda Capture Expressions you can omit the counter vairable in the outer scope and simply use an initializer expression to create `i` as a member of the lambda:

```
std::for_each(begin(v), end(v), [i = 0] (int x) mutable {
    std::cout << "[" << i++ << "]=" << x << std::endl;
});
```

Comment: I like this solution better than mine, actually. With lambdas, there really is no need for a custom algorithm or a special functor.

Comment: You can avoid reseting the index by capturing by value, and then marking the lambda as `mutable`.  Then it'll make a copy of index when created, and then be able to update the value in the local copy.

Comment: @DaveS That's a good point. I've updated the lambda expression in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion `std::for_each` is mostly obsolete with ranged based `for( : )` loops, with the possible exception of iterating over a subrange.

And even for that I simply have a `range_view` `template` that works with ranged based `for( : )` loops.  A `range_view` is a simple structure with `begin()` and `end()` methods that return iterators: such an object can be passed to ranged-based for loops:

```
template<typename Iterator>
struct range_view {
  Iterator b, e;
  Iterator begin() const { return b; }
  Iterator end() const { return e; }
};
template<typename Iterator>
range_view<Iterator> make_range_view( Iterator b, Iterator e ) {
  return {b,e};
}
template<typename Container>
auto make_range_view( Container&& c )
-> decltype( make_range_view( std::begin(c), std::end(c) ) )
{   return ( make_range_view( std::begin(c), std::end(c) ) ); }
```

If I needed the index, I would either use an `indexes` range, or if extremely keen do a range-`zip` adaptor on the index range and the original container (generating a range of tuples).  `indexes` is an iterator-over-contiguous-integers (`boost` has such types), and `zip` is the operation of taking two ranges or containers and returning a range over `tuple` or `pair`s of the data.

Now we could instead fix up yours.  Upgrade `()` to use perfect forwarding and `auto->decltype` return values.  But I would not bother: the `std` algorithms have their place, but `for_each` is rarely worth it.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What is range_view and zip adaptors?

Answer (score 0):

I made this little algorithm, based on for_each:

```
namespace estd {

template<class InputIt, class BinaryFunction>
BinaryFunction for_each_with_index(
    InputIt first, InputIt last, BinaryFunction f)
{
  for (auto index = 0; first != last; ++first, ++index) {
    f(*first, index);
  }
  return f;
}

}
```

Then I was able to write a simple example like this:

```
estd::for_each_with_index(
    begin(strings_),
    end(strings_),
    [&sx, &sy](const auto& s, auto index) {
       // Do something with my string and integer index
});
```

estd::for_each_with_index will work with any forward iterator (anything that provides *, ++, !=).